# What's the equivalent of UIBezierPath in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x, beziers

I'm beginner in Cocos2d-x , and i want to implement this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/38918/paintcode-tutorial-bezier-paths) with Cocos2d-x v.3 cpp, but the problem i dont know if there's UIBezierPath in cocos2d-x.

Could you help me to draw the Bezier Arrow please?